# Densification (void filling) methods for polar point cloud projection images

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, scipy

this will be my first post here on stackoverflow, english is also not my primary language so I apologize in advance for any confusion.

I have a program that is able to take in a camera position (x, y, z), and return a panoramic projection of a point cloud at said positions. In simple terms (since the workings on this code are not too relevant to the question) the points surrounding the camera location in the point cloud are projected unto a 2D image. [Here is a sample image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D73jC.jpg)

I am trying to come up with a densification algorithm to increase the density of colored pixels in said image. Essentially ensuring that regions where there is a large amount of colored pixels are continuous and uninterrupted by black voids (which is a result of projecting a point cloud into an image).

What I am looking for from the community is to hopefully start a conversation on some methods for void filling that could fit this particular scenario that I may have overlooked during my research, and to hear some advice from you experts regarding this matter.

I have attempted several methods for densification with varying degrees of success in Python:

- Void filling via nearest neighbor search algorithms: I've tried several variations of void filling methods via nearest neighbor search to fill black pixels with the average pixel values of its colored neighbors within the set radius. I have also tried 2 conditional methods to specify where the algorithm should be applied (so as to avoid unnecessary filling in areas such as the "sky"):

  1. Creating a [binary mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcmff.png) for the image from a combination of
     gaussian blurring, erosion/dilation and finally binarization. [End result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NX0ZA.jpg)
  2. Using the ratio of black pixels to colored pixels in the neighborhood, and performing void filling
     only if a certain value is met
- Morphological operations such as closing, with variable kernels depending on how far from the "horizon" (center of the image) the pixels are. [End result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcJpR.jpg)
- Unstructured data interpolation using scipy.interpolate.griddata. I would post the final result but let's just say the results were... not promising.

If any of you have any advice regarding any methods that could serve my purposes, or if I may have missed some key info in my question I am all years. Thank you.